# Install g++ 4.9 on Mint 17.2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, installation, g++4.9

I'm trying to install g++ 4.9 or greater in order to build mapbox on Android. The instructions state I need g++ 4.9 or greater. I found the following instructions, but they don't work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
```

The last command says:

```
~ $ sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'g++-4.9' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried from Synaptic Package Manager and got the following:

```
g++:
  Depends: cpp (>=4:4.9-1ubuntu7) but 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 is to be installed
  Depends: gcc (>=4:4.9-1ubuntu7) but 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 is to be installed
 Depends: g++-4.9 (>=4.9) but it is not installable
 Depends: gcc-4.9 (>=4.9) but it is not installable
```

How can I get g++ 4.9 on my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: what does it say when you do `apt-get update`? Also, you might want to try using apt-get to remove g++, or whatever package you used to install g++ before. if you used a ppa to install that one also, it might be a good idea to clean house

Comment: sudo apt-get update returns a long list of stuff, but ends like so:  Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Fetched 2,102 kB in 21s (99.8 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: I've tried to remove, but also this is a brand new install of mint 17.2. If you have a specific command, I can try that.

Comment: So, I am running mint 17.2 also, and somehow I got g++-4.9 on it. I don't remember how exactly. I am planning to reinstall shortly so I guess I will have to figure it out again shortly.

Comment: FWIW I ran apt-file to see where it came from: http://hastebin.com/aforuviner.js i'm not sure exactly what 'hardening-wrapper' is, it is described here: http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/hardening-wrapper

Comment: mitch: if I were you I would try to figure out what package is associated to `4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6` and remove it, and then try to install 4.9 again

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not experienced at linux administration. How do I find the 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6? Is there a command or UI I should run? I'm using xfce if that helps.

Comment: @Mitch, I successfully installed g++-4.9 on Mint 17.2 after some research, can you confirm this solution ?

Comment: I have installed gcc-4.9 (with g++ and other compilers) in Linux Mint 17.2 several times (desktops and laptop). After adding toolchain repo, run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Then install g++ and etc. This way you can also safely uninstall gcc-4.8 stuffs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to install g++-4.9 on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela

1. Go to **menu -> Administration -> Software sources**
2. Click on **Additional repositories** and then **Getdeb**
3. Click on Edit URL...
4. Replace **deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps**

   by

   **deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu wily-getdeb apps**

   and click on **Update the cache**

[image]

5. At this point you can go with

   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
   >
   > sudo apt-get update
   >
   > sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

[image]

You can invoke your g++ like this:

> g++-4.9

[image]

Now you have g++ 4.9.3 installed

And as an add, you can have the latest g++-5 (g++ 5.2.1) compiler

> sudo apt-get install g++-5

[image]

Comment: Good solution. Though after adding toolchain repo `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` would suffice.

Comment: Another series of things you can try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312620/how-do-i-install-gcc-4-8-1-on-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: Oh I already looked at that, unfortunately there is a problem with: update-alternatives. It can't be found or I miss something else for that. Here is the page who helped me since we have to go with a source having the gcc-4.9 package: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/13/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-14-programs/

Comment: Worked!  A few minor differences between what I did and what you described, but looks good. One thing, I seem to still have 4.8 installed, which I assume is fine. Also, my "Software Sources" wasn't located where you described, but easy enough to find anyway. Thank you. Now I can move forward.

Comment: Many thanks! This worked like charm! I got gcc-5.4.1 installed today.